# Print a table of numbers in decimal and 2**i bases

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory, base-conversion, binary

Computers live by binary. All programmers know binary.

But the `2**x` bases are often neglected as non-practical, while they have beautiful relations to binary.

To show you one example of such a beatiful relation, 19 will be my testimonial.

```
19 10011 103 23 13 j
```

- 19 is decimal, included for clarity.
- 10011 is 19 in binary.
- 103, in base 4 is made starting from binary this way:

  - log2(4) == 2, let us remember two.
  - Pad 10011 so that it has a multiple of 2 length -> 010011
  - Take digits 2 by 2 from left to right and treat them as 2-digits binary numbers:

    - 01 -> 1
    - 00 -> 0
    - 11 -> 3

  **Done**, 10011 in base-4 is 103.

For base 8, do the same but 3-by-3 as log2(8) = 3.

- Pad 010011
- 010 -> 2
- 011 -> 3

  23, **Done**.

For base 16, do the same but 4-by-4 as log2(16) = 4.

- Pad 00010011
- 0001 -> 1
- 0011 -> 3

  13, **Done**.

**Task**

Given a max number as input, you shall output a table

```
base-ten-i base-two-i base-four-i base-eight-i base-sixteen-i base-thirtytwo-i
```

for i that goes from 0 to n inclusive. Binary numbers are the epitome of the absolute minimum needed to work, so your code should be as short as possible.

**Restrictions and bonuses**

- Base-ten -> binary and binary -> Base-ten built-ins are considered loopholes as Base-a -> Base-b are.
- If you generate all the `2**i` (for i > 2) bases by using the relations over mentioned you get a `*0.6` bonus, but general base conversions (written by yourself) are allowed.

**Example table**

```
> 32
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1
2 10 2 2 2 2
3 11 3 3 3 3
4 100 10 4 4 4
5 101 11 5 5 5
6 110 12 6 6 6
7 111 13 7 7 7
8 1000 20 10 8 8
9 1001 21 11 9 9
10 1010 22 12 a a
11 1011 23 13 b b
12 1100 30 14 c c
13 1101 31 15 d d
14 1110 32 16 e e
15 1111 33 17 f f
16 10000 100 20 10 g
17 10001 101 21 11 h
18 10010 102 22 12 i
19 10011 103 23 13 j
20 10100 110 24 14 k
21 10101 111 25 15 l
22 10110 112 26 16 m
23 10111 113 27 17 n
24 11000 120 30 18 o
25 11001 121 31 19 p
26 11010 122 32 1a q
27 11011 123 33 1b r
28 11100 130 34 1c s
29 11101 131 35 1d t
30 11110 132 36 1e u
31 11111 133 37 1f v
32 100000 200 40 20 10
```

Comment: Downvoted because of "You must generate all the 2**i (for i > 2) bases by using the relations over mentioned". Requiring a specific algorithm removes a lot of what makes code golf interesting. You can ban built-in base conversion functions while still allowing a choice of algorithm.

Comment: @xnor now using my method only gives a bonus, to give more freedom to golfers

Comment: I'm not a fan of the bonus either. It effectively means you have to use either a built-in or your algorithm, and no other algorithm can be viable.

Comment: @xnor built-ins are not allowed. A general converter will be shorter, so I give a bonus if you use my contrived conversion rules

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 54 * 0.6 = 32.4 bytes

```
q~){_5,f{)L@{2md@+\}h(%/Wf%W%{{\2*+}*_9>{'W+}&}%S\}N}/
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~)%7B_5%2Cf%7B)L%40%7B2md%40%2B%5C%7Dh(%25%2FWf%25W%25%7B%7B%5C2*%2B%7D*_9%3E%7B'W%2B%7D%26%7D%25S%5C%7DN%7D%2F&input=32)

For reference, here is a shorter solution which doesn't qualify for the bonus (at 39 bytes):

```
q~){:X5{SLX{2I)#md_9>{'W+}&@+\}h;}fIN}/
```

Comment: I updated the challange, you may claim a 0.6* bonus if you used my method

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 52 * 0.6 = 31.2 bytes

```
L?b+%b2y/b2YVUhQjd+NmjkX|_uL++GGHZ_McyNd]ZUQ+jkUTGS5
```

[Test it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%3Fb%2B%25b2y%2Fb2YVUhQjd%2BNmjkX%7C_uL%2B%2BGGHZ_McyNd%5DZUQ%2BjkUTGS5&input=33&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A15%0A77%0A12345678929&debug=0)

My non-bonus answer is 39 bytes

```
M?G+g/GHH@+jkUTG%GHkVUhQjd+N|R0gLN^L2S5
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>232</s> <s>230</s> <s>233</s> 217 * 0.6 = 130.2

no chance beating the golfing languages, but I liked the challenge.

```
for(;$d<=$n;$d++){echo'
',$d|0;for($k=$d,$b='';$k;$k>>=1)$b=($k&1).$b;for($w=1;$w<6;$w++,print" $z"|' 0')for($z='',$k=strlen($b);-$w<$k-=$w;$z=($e>9?chr($e+87):$e).$z)for($e=0,$y=1,$j=$w;$j--;$y*=2) $e+=$y*$b[$j+$k];}
```

- usage: prepend `$n=32;` or replace `$n` with `32` (or any other non-negative integer); call via cli
- If that is not accepted, replace `$n` with `$_GET[n]` (+6/+3.6) and call either in the browser
  or on cli with `php-cgi -f bases.php -n=32`
- Replace the line break with `<br>` or prepend `<pre>` to test in browser
- may throw notices for undefined variables and unintialized string offsets in newer PHP versions.
  Remove E_NOTICE from error_reporting (prepend `error_reporting(0);`) to suppress them.
- tested in 5.6

break down:

```
for(;$d<=$n;$d++) // loop decimal $d from 0 to $n
{
    echo'
',$d|0; // print line break and decimal
    for($k=$d,$b='';$k;$k>>=1)$b=($k&1).$b; // convert $d to binary
    for($w=1;$w<6;$w++,
        print" $z"|' 0' // print number generated in inner loop (echo doesn´t work here)
    )
        for($z='',$k=strlen($b);-$w<$k-=$w; // loop from end by $w
            $z=($e>9?chr($e+87):$e).$z // prepend digit created in body
        )
            for($e=0,$y=1,$j=$w;$j--;$y*=2) $e+=$y*$b[$j+$k]; // convert chunk to 2**$w
}
```

major edit:

- used some index magic to revamp the inner loop -> now works backwards on the whole string (no more padding, no more splitting or copying the binary)
- moved parts of the loop bodies to the heads to eliminate braces
- had to add <s>7</s> 4 bytes to fix the decimal 0 results after the revamp

## non-bonus version, 142 bytes

```
for(;$d<=$n;$d++,print'
',$d|0)for($w=1;$w<6;$w++,print" $z"|' 0')for($k=$d,$y=1,$z='';$k&&$y<<=$w;$k>>=$w)$z=(9<($e=$k%$y)?chr($e+87):$e).$z;
```

**PHP beats Python?**
Even if I added the 6 (3.6) bytes to make the snippet a program, I´d still beat Python (223*0.6=133.8 or 148 non-bonus vs. 158). Amazing.

Comment: I get an error 'Undefined variable: n :1' and I think that you can save 1 byte by removing a space after the `for` keyword in the outermost for-loop.

Comment: @TuukkaX: see usage: $n must be define before the snippet. I found that byte, but thanks. And one more: `"\n"` -> physical line break.

Comment: but I had to add 3 bytes to print the first 0. (that or 5 bytes to init the variable).

Answer (score 0):

### Python3 - <strike>189, 167, 166</strike> 150 bytes

```
for i in range(int(input())+1):f=lambda b,n=i,c="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv":n<b and c[n]or f(b,n//b)+c[n%b];print(i,f(2),f(4),f(8),f(16),f(32))
```

Saved 16 bytes with the help of @[LeakyNun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun%20LeakyNun)!

### Bonus version - <strike>296 * 0.6 = 177.6</strike> 279 * 0.6 = 167.4 bytes

```
p=lambda b,c:"".join(str(int(b[i:i+c],2))for i in range(0,len(b),c))
z=lambda s:len(s)%2 and s or "0"+s
for i in range(int(input())+1):f=lambda n,b,c="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv":n<b and c[n]or f(n//b,b)+c[n%b];v=f(i,2);d=z(v);print(i,v,p(d,2),p(d,3),p(d,4),p(d,5),f(i,32))
```

Slightly more readable version of the bonus version.

```
p=lambda b,c:"".join(str(int(b[i:i+c],2))for i in range(0,len(b),c))
z=lambda s:len(s)%2 and s or "0"+s
for i in range(int(input())+1):
    f=lambda n,b,c="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv":n<b and c[n] or f(n//b,b) + c[n%b]
    v=f(i,2)
    d=z(v)
    print(i,v,p(d,2),p(d,3),p(d,4),p(d,5),f(i,32))
```

Comment: I am pretty certain that the bonus does not apply. You are not using binary to produce the base 2**x numbers.

Comment: @Titus Oh, I understood the bonus wrong then. I'll edit the byte count. Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure `"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv"` is shorter than `from string import* digits+ascii_lowercase`

Comment: @LeakyNun Oops. You're right. I only thought of how short it is to write `digits+ascii_lowercase` :D. Thanks!

Comment: 150 bytes: `for i in range(int(input())+1):f=lambda n=i,b,c="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv":n<b and c[n]or f(n//b,b)+c[n%b];print(i,f(2),f(4),f(8),f(16),f(32))` (one line)

Comment: I translated your recursive approach to PHP (190*1) and modified it to work on binary chunks (246*0.6=147.6). Dare to try?

Comment: @Titus Go for it! :)

Comment: @LeakyNun the `n=i` and `b` need to swap places in the parameter list, since `i` is being before `b` and being a default parameter.

Comment: Actually I was asking if You would dare to reach for the bonus. :D

Comment: @Titus Ohh :D I interpreted differently. I can give it a shot if I find a reasonable short way to do it :P

Comment: @LeakyNun Hmm. Ran your 150 byte solution and it sadly doesn't work :( The f lambda doesn't return binary values, because of the `n=i`. I have to edit it a bit.

Comment: @Titus There you go! A little bit long, but it's a beautiful craft :D

Comment: [It works](http://ideone.com/A5TJLR)

Comment: @LeakyNun Yeah, you're right. I passed th arguments to the `f` lambda in the wrong order.

Comment: if I am not mistaken: -7 for `c=lambda n:(n,chr(n+87))[n>9]`

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 80 bytes (non-bonus version)

```
m=ARGV[0].to_i;(0..m).each{|n|puts [10,2,4,8,16,32].map{|b|n.to_s(b)}.join(' ')}
```